# How to get div children using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to get children elements of a div using puppeteer.
this is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = 'https://example.com/'; 

//browser initialization
async function initBrowser() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  return browser;
}

async function getPage(browser) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  return page;
}

async function getNewMessage(page) {
  let els = [];

  els = await page.$$('div.class');

  for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    const imgSrc = await els[i]
      .$('div.class2')
      .$eval('img', (el) => el.getAttribute('src'));
    console.log(imgSrc);
    const link = await els[i].$eval('div.class3', (elem) => elem.texContent);
    console.log(link);
  }
}

async function loading() {
  const browser = await initBrowser();
  const page = await getPage(browser);
  await getNewMessage(page);
}

loading();
```

the page structure looks like this:

```
<div class="class">
  <div class="class2"> 
    <img src="..."> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="class3">
    message
  </div>
</div>
```

the error I get is:
Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector "img".

I actually think I found out what the problem is, because in some cases I get the image. I think that when I try to get the image it is still loading and I can't catch it.

Comment: Can you show the live page, please? The code seems wrong, too since `elements[i]` doesn't exist. See [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen my bad, fixed, was using foreach instead of for, the problem is the same

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not reproducible because this code should work fine on the snippet you shared. There must be some other behavior in the live page having to do with visibility or JS that's causing results to be different.

Comment: I think problem might be here: `page.$$("div.class")` What is the class name?

Comment: @ggorlen I updated with the full code, (of course the url is just an example, I can't give you the real one)

Comment: @Abdulhakim the class name is "class" as I. wrote in the page structure example

Answer (score 1):

This code is missing an `await`:

```js
const imgSrc = await els[i]
  .$('div.class2')
  .$eval('img', (el) => el.getAttribute('src'));
```

It's not possible to chain like this, because `.$` returns a promise that isn't awaited, so you're calling `.$eval` on a plain old JS promise rather than a Puppeteer function. The fix would be to `await` each new Puppeteer call on a separate line and use intermediate variables.

```js
const div = await els[i].$('div.class2');
const imgSrc = await div.$eval('img', (el) => el.getAttribute('src'));
```

Technically, you could chain by tossing in parenthesis and `await`s inline, but it'd be harder to read:

```js
const imgSrc = await (await els[i].$('div.class2'))
  .$eval('img', (el) => el.getAttribute('src'));
```

Better yet is to combine both selectors into one. There's no need for the two-step procedure:

```js
const imgSrc = await div.$eval('div.class2 img', (el) => el.getAttribute('src'));
```

Following that logic a step further, you might be able to skip all of the intermediate selectors, using one `.$$eval` per array you want to build. You can optionally merge them if you know they'll be the same length:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const html = `<div class="class">
  <div class="class2"> 
    <img src="..."> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="class3">
    message
  </div>
</div>`.repeat(2); // repeat the structure for demonstration purposes

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.waitForSelector("div.class div.class2 img");
  const imgSrcs = await page.$$eval(
    "div.class div.class2 img",
    els => els.map(e => e.getAttribute("src"))
  );
  const textContents = await page.$$eval(
    "div.class div.class3",
    els => els.map(e => e.textContent)
  );
  const data = imgSrcs.map((e, i) => ({
    src: e, text: textContents[i]
  }));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "src": "...",
    "text": "\n    message\n  "
  },
  {
    "src": "...",
    "text": "\n    message\n  "
  }
]
```

Comment: the source I get is: data:image/png;base64 (some more characters here), instead of http://exampleimage.com